# Polymer, evaluate element based off object

Tags: javascript, polymer

I am using the tile example from polymers neon elements - and I am trying to make each expanded tile unique. My first try on how to do this was to pass a string in with the grid items like

```
 {
      value: 1,
      color: 'blue',
      template: 'slide-1'
 }
```

And have that element be evaluated when rendered in a new element something like this. (this is the card template itself)

```
<template>

<div id="fixed" class$="[[_computeFixedBackgroundClass(color)]]"></div>

<div id="card" class$="[[_computeCardClass(color)]]">
  <[[item.template]]></[[item.template]]>
</div>
```

This does not work - however I am wondering if there is some way to do this so I can load custom elements for the content of each card. For reference -https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/neon-animation?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=neon-animated-pages  , it is the grid example and I am trying to replace the content of each card once it is clicked on ( the fullsize-page-with-card.html, here is all the html for it - https://github.com/PolymerElements/neon-animation/tree/master/demo/grid ). Is this the wrong way of approaching this? Or maybe I have some syntax wrong here. Thanks!

Edit : OK, So I can send it through if i add it to the click to open the card like so

```
   scope._onTileClick = function(event) {
        this.$['fullsize-card'].color = event.detail.data.color;
        this.$['fullsize-card'].template = event.detail.data.template;
        this.$.pages.selected = 1;
    };
```

and in the card's properties like so

```
 template: {
    type: String
  },
```

So I can then evaluate it as [[template]] , however - the question still remains how to call a custom element (dynamically) using this string. I could pass a couple of properties and fill in a card or form so they are unique, but i think I would have much more creative freedom if I could call custom elements inside each card.

Answer (score 1):

I have an element that allows referenced templates. There are a couple of others other there, but this one also allows data bindings to work: https://github.com/Trakkasure/dom-bindref